# Sobel edge detector on video - not detected in the output file

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, edge-detection, sobel

I am applying sobel edge detector in a video using OpenCV. I can see the result in a window and then I am writing the video. Even though I can see the right result on the window, the result in the output file is not the same.

Here is the code and what I can see in the window and in the output file. Any idea what can cause this?

```
if between (cap,0,25000):  #Apply results on specific milliseconds of the video
        Sobel operator - I still need to add colors
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)              
        frame = cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,5)  

   out.write(frame)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = 0.2, fy = 0.2, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)   
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        
        
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print ("done")
```

Comment: Sobel output is float per your cv2.CV_64F. That won't be visible since it is in the range of 0 to 1 but your written video frame wants it to be 0 to 255. So you need to scale your results by multiplying by 255 and then clip to range 0 to 255 and save as uint8. `frame = (255*cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,5) ).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)`.  Be sure to import `numpy as np`

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered.
I am adding the answer again here:

Sobel output is float per your cv2.CV_64F. That won't be visible since it is in the range of 0 to 1 but your written video frame wants it to be 0 to 255. So you need to scale your results by multiplying by 255 and then clip to range 0 to 255 and save as uint8. frame = (255*cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,5) ).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8). Be sure to import numpy as np

Comment: Would be nice if you reference where you copied that!

Comment: Here is how I modified the code:                                                                                                    
    if between (cap,20000,22000):  
          #Sobel operator - horizontal
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)              
        frame = cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,15,15,4)
        frame = (255*cv2.Sobel(frame,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,15,15,4) ).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)